# Trusted Host Settings Not enabled

Tags: configuration

In the settings.php file if the site, I added the following line.

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^www\.example\.com$',
);
```

I'm using Drupal 8.2.6.

Do I need to add the proxy address too, or my IP? It is a single domain.

Answer (score 0):

Every entry in the array contains a RegEx. So you must escape the dot too.

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array( '^www\.example\.com$' );
```

This will match the exact the host "www.example.com".

Comment: thank you Alexander I've done it $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array( 
    '^www\.nonigesto\.org$', 
 '^novigesto\.org$', 
 '^xxxx-xxxxx\.xxxxxxx\.xxx$', 
  );  the server is a big name with points every point is replaced by \. right? and IP is needed?